# Sed not finding file if it's quoted

Tags: linux, sed

I have a shell script that's executing a sed command. Upon variable expansion, it quotes the filename.

```bsh
sed -i "$3d" $filename
```

becomes

```bsh
sed -i 1d '~/file'
```

as shown by the debugging flag `-x`.

When ran, this produces

```
sed: can't read ~/file: No such file or directory
```

When I try to run the command manually, the same thing happens, unless I remove the quotes.

```bsh
sed -i 1d ~/file
```

Running without quotes produces the desired output.

Comment: Please post the part where you assign the variables. Also, what is "the debugging flag `-x`"? My version of sed doesn't appear to have this.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate. In addition to tilde not expanding when it's quoted, the output produced under `set -x` is not on a form suitable for execution. It's is purely _shell tracing output_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the part that you don't show. Somewhere before that line you have something like this:

```
filename="~/file"
```

So the problem is not that the later use of `$filename` is quoted, it isn't quoted and that can introduce other problems if the name contains spaces.

The `~` is expanded by the shell to the home directory if it is the first character of a word. It is not expanded if it is the result of a variable expansion.

You can use `$HOME` instead of `~`:

```
filename=$HOME/file
sed -i "$3d" $filename
```

or better with quotes:

```
filename="$HOME/file"
sed -i "$3d" "$filename"
```

Comment: `filename=~/file` expands `~` for me as expected in both `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: Yes, so the assignment to `filename` must be quoted.

Comment: Their issue is trying to run the output of `set -x` (or at least copy-paste it), which shows the filename in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the quotation marks around the filename. They prevent your shell to expand `~` to your home folder. So `sed` is looking for a folder called `~`.

Make sure `$filename` doesn't contain the quotation mark or use the real path instead of `~`.